# take numeric value without label in line, regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Input:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'text':['value 123* 333','122* 666','722 888*']})
print(df)
             text
0  value 123* 333
1        122* 666
2        722 888*
```

I need to extract from `df['text']` only numeric values, but withou `*`label
my code:

```
df.text.str.extract(r'([0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
```

But with this code, values with the `*` char on the right are returned.

Expected output:

```
text
333
666
722
```

Comment: The dot must be escaped in a regex to match a literal dot. E.g. `df['text'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)')`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew not working, wrong regex, output with it is:`123,
122,
722`

Comment: Look at your example and the expected output: how come you expect `333.1` if there is only `value 123* 333`, `122* 666` and `722 888*`? Please fix the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why you closed it ? i am not asking about how to escape special character, please re open it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew those are stings in each line, one column , index=0,1,2

Comment: So you want `df['text'].str.extract(r'(?=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?))\1(?!\*)')`? Please clarify: can you have fractional values in the data? Also, why isn't the dot escaped in your pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes that what i need, thanks

Comment: Ok, I had to fix the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
df['text'].str.extract(r'(?=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?))\1(?!\*)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/upKQeA/1). Or, you may also require a word boundary on the left with `r'\b(?=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?))\1(?!\*)'`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/upKQeA/2).

**Regex details**

- `(?=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?))` - a positive lookahead that requires and captures into Group 1 the following sequence of patterns immediately on the right:

  - `[0-9]+` -  1+ digits
  - `(?:\.[0-9]+)?`  - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits.
- `\1` - the value of Group 1
- `(?!\*)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right, there is a `*` char.

See the Python test:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'text':['value 123* 333','122* 666','722 888*']})
>>> df['text'].str.extract(r'(?=([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?))\1(?!\*)')
0    333
1    666
2    722
Name: text, dtype: object
>>>
```

Comment: hi again, i have one more question, if my values are starting from `#` and I want to use same regex without taking this `#` eg:`122* #666 one 2` expected value : `666` your regex: `(?=(\#[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?))\1(?!\*)` <- i have added `\#`, but i am receiving `#666` not `666`, Could give me a tip how to get it in this regex?

Comment: @sygneto If you need to extract the numbers after `#`, use `df['text'].str.extract(r'#([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)')`.

Comment: yes thats correct, but i want to still dont take values without `*` so when i have case  `#1615* #666` i want `666` only

Comment: @sygneto I probably made it too complex for nothing. You may use `r'#([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\b(?!\*)'` and for the original problem, you may use `r'\b([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\b(?!\*)'`. I just wanted to make use of an atomic group but since Python `re` does not support it, I used a known equivalent, but word boundaries - in this case - might suffice.